# Track mb used per each user

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to figure out a way to implement a tracking system based on how many megabytes a user has used for a MongoDB database.

Say I have a email field value for each document associated with a user (`myemail@example.com`).
A user can append new documents to multiple collections in the database whenever he / she wants through a web-application, but is not allowed to exceed 100MB in total storage.

Basically I want to track when all associated documents for each email has exceeded 100MB, respectively.

How can I with high performance and accuracy track this?

Thanks!

Comment: There are probably multiple ways you can go about keeping track of this. However, I don't think there is any built-in way to track the "size of all documents containing some field value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$bsonSize](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bsonSize/) to figure out how much space a set of documents occupies.

MongoDB used to have a quota system with MMAP but this isn't a feature available with Wired Tiger.